# WSO2 API Manager: How do I log the fulle (http) SOAP response

Tags: wso2

How do I log the SOAP response messages (complete http response) when I invoke a service on the WSO2 AM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see all the messages that are passing through,  you can enable the wire level logs. It will log all http messages.  Please uncomment following two properties in "log4j.properties" file which can be found at /repository/conf directory

> uncomment the following logs to see HTTP headers and messages
>   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
>   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG

Answer (score 1):

You can use log mediator to log the response. Add [log mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Log+Mediator) with level="full" at your out sequence of the API(repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api) configuration. After editing the sequence, restart the server.

OR else, [you can define your custom sequence](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension) to log message and you can add that when you try to publish the API.